# MVC-5 Razor Validation Errors showing on page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an insert page when I go to the insert page all the validation field is being shown,

```
[Required(ErrorMessage ="Please Enter Name")]
        public string ccname { get; set; }
```

This is my class where I declared string `ccname` with required validation message

> ENTER NAME

and it supposed to appear when user clicks on insert without entering data in `ccname`

but validatation message is being shown on the page load

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ccname, new { @class = "textboxstyle" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ccname)
```

I tried few things but nothing works,

here is an example

in my controller I added `ModelState.clear();`

```
public ActionResult insert()
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View();
}
```

and in my view I changed the code from

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ccname, new { @class = "textboxstyle" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ccname)
```

to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ccname, new { @class = "textboxstyle" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ccname,"",new {@style= ".validation-summary-valid { display:none; }" })
```

but neither of these works

what should I do now?

Comment: Is the `insert()` method your actual controller method or just an example?

Comment: i didn't written anything in my insert `[httppost]` method

Comment: In the first place your provided code is not going to work because you are not passing `view model` to your `view` .

Comment: @MumbaiWadala that wasn't the question. If this is not your actual code for your Get method, then please post the actual code.

Comment: @Marco this is my actual method of my controller


this method is triggered on pageload
`public ActionResult insert()
        {
            return View();
        }`

Comment: decorate your action method with [HttpPost]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:**

**Model:**

```
public class MyModel
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please Enter Name")]
  public string ccname { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController:Controller
{
[HttpGet]
 ActionResult Insert()
 {
     var model =new MyModel();
      return View(model); 
 }

 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 ActionResult Insert(MyModel model)
 {
     if(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
      //Do something
       return View(); 
     }   
      return View(model); 
 }
}
```

**View**

**Insert.cshtml**

```
@model MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ccname, new { @class = "textboxstyle" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ccname)
  <input type="submit" value="Insert" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```